# How to claim the custom attribute from Azure AD with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

I am doing SSO Single Sign ON with Azure Active Directory from AWS Cognito.

I am able to get the email as claim but i am not getting the name in claim, when i get the Access_Token / Id_Token ? anyone came across this issue ?

Please assist ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) is what you are looking for.
It will allow you to add claims to the token.